# How can I use Podman from behind a proxy?

Tags: podman

I have a windows host

I have installed podman-desktop

I use a VPN to connect to my work

I use a local proxy to reach the internet (127.0.0.1:3128)

My local proxy works very well with Firefox in particular

I tried to do a

podman pull redhat/ubi8-micro

many times

This does not work

From the Windows terminal (CMD) I initialise the variables:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

and

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

and I run

```
podman pull podman/hello
```

and I get

```
docker run quay.io/podman/hello

Unable to find image 'quay.io/podman/hello:latest' locally

docker: initializing source docker://quay.io/podman/hello:latest: pinging container registry quay.io: Get "https://quay.io/v2

/": dial tcp: lookup quay.io: Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

```
nslookup quay.io
```

returns correct answers

```
curl quay.io
```

also

how do I make it work?

Comment: You *did* set the proxy details in podman-desktop, diidn't you? It's just that you don't mention it. The podman commands aren't actually running on your windows host, but in a VM run by podman desktop

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an 's' in http:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Comment: it's deliberate, there's no s, because my local proxy is on http.